# Вывод не корректной директории в PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside2

Я использую команду:

```
directory_file = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "", "*txt")
```

при ее использование появляется диалоговое окно с выбором файлов с расширением **`.txt`**, но при этом в переменную записывается не только директория файл, но и другая информация, 
например:

```
('G:/PyCharm/PyCharmProject/projectSAFTD_x32/OGE/name.txt', 'All Files (*)')
```

как сделать так, чтобы выводилась только директория файла?

**main.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from crypto import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.Qt import *

import rsa

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowTitle("Automatic OGE verification system ver.00.04.75")

        (self.key_pub, self.key_priv) = rsa.newkeys(1024)

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.information)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.app_information)

    def information(self):
        self.key_crypto = self.lineEdit_13.text()
        self.directory_file_ver = self.lineEdit_14.text()
        self.directory_save = self.lineEdit_15.text()
        self.directory_key = self.lineEdit_16.text()
        self.name_key = self.lineEdit_17.text()

        self.key_task()

    def key_task(self):
        self.number_1 = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.number_2 = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        self.number_3 = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        self.number_4 = self.lineEdit_4.text()
        self.number_5 = self.lineEdit_5.text()
        self.number_6 = self.lineEdit_6.text()
        self.number_7 = self.lineEdit_7.text()
        self.number_8 = self.lineEdit_8.text()
        self.number_9 = self.lineEdit_9.text()
        self.number_10 = self.lineEdit_10.text()
        self.number_11 = self.lineEdit_11.text()
        self.number_12 = self.lineEdit_12.text()

        self.key_task_crypto()

    def key_task_crypto(self):
        self.number_1_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_1.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_2_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_2.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_3_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_3.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_4_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_4.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_5_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_5.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_6_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_6.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_7_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_7.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_8_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_8.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_9_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_9.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_10_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_10.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_11_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_11.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_12_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_12.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)

        self.load_key_task_crypto()

    def load_key_task_crypto(self):
        k = [self.number_1_crypto, self.number_2_crypto, self.number_3_crypto, self.number_4_crypto,
             self.number_5_crypto, self.number_6_crypto, self.number_7_crypto, self.number_8_crypto,
             self.number_9_crypto, self.number_10_crypto, self.number_11_crypto, self.number_12_crypto,
             self.key_crypto]

        directory_save_key = self.directory_key + self.name_key + ".txt"

        with open(directory_save_key, "w") as f:
            f.write("\n".join(str(item) for item in k))

    def app_information(self):
        directory_file, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "", "*txt")

        print(directory_file)
        x = open(directory_file, 'r')
        print(x)

        self.number_1_decrypto = x.readline(1)
        self.number_2_decrypto = x.readline(2)
        self.number_3_decrypto = x.readline(3)
        self.number_4_decrypto = x.readline(4)
        self.number_5_decrypto = x.readline(5)
        self.number_6_decrypto = x.readline(6)
        self.number_7_decrypto = x.readline(7)
        self.number_8_decrypto = x.readline(8)
        self.number_9_decrypto = x.readline(9)
        self.number_10_decrypto = x.readline(10)
        self.number_11_decrypto = x.readline(11)
        self.number_12_decrypto = x.readline(12)
        print(self.number_1_decrypto)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    app.setStyle("Fusion")

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**crypto.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 514)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab_3)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.tab_3)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.gridLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox)
        self.gridLayout_4.setObjectName("gridLayout_4")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.lineEdit_7 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_7.setObjectName("lineEdit_7")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_7, 6, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_8 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_8.setObjectName("lineEdit_8")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_8, 7, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_9 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_9.setObjectName("lineEdit_9")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_9, 8, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_11 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_11.setObjectName("lineEdit_11")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_11, 10, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_3, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_5, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_4, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_6 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_6, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_10 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_10.setObjectName("lineEdit_10")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_10, 9, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_12 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_12.setObjectName("lineEdit_12")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_12, 11, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_3, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_4, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_5, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_6, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_7, 6, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_8, 7, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_9, 8, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_10, 9, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_11, 10, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_12, 11, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_4.addLayout(self.gridLayout_3, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.groupBox_2 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.groupBox)
        self.groupBox_2.setObjectName("groupBox_2")
        self.gridLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox_2)
        self.gridLayout_5.setObjectName("gridLayout_5")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 7, 0, 1, 2)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 6, 0, 1, 2)
        self.label_19 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_19.setObjectName("label_19")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_19, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_14 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        self.lineEdit_14.setObjectName("lineEdit_14")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit_14, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_17 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        self.lineEdit_17.setObjectName("lineEdit_17")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit_17, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_14.setObjectName("label_14")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_14, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_15 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_15.setObjectName("label_15")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_15, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBox_2)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.comboBox, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_15 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        self.lineEdit_15.setObjectName("lineEdit_15")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit_15, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_16 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_16.setObjectName("label_16")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_16, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.pushButton, 9, 0, 1, 2)
        self.lineEdit_16 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        self.lineEdit_16.setObjectName("lineEdit_16")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit_16, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_18 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_18.setObjectName("label_18")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_18, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_13, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_13 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        self.lineEdit_13.setObjectName("lineEdit_13")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit_13, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.groupBox_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.groupBox, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.tab_5 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_5.setObjectName("tab_5")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_5, "")
        self.tab_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_4.setObjectName("tab_4")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_4, "")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_17 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_17.setObjectName("label_17")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_17, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.tabWidget.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>Дишифрование файлов</p></body></html>"))
        self.tabWidget.setWhatsThis(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>Дишифрование</p></body></html>"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответы на задания ОГЭ с КРАТКИМ ОТВЕТОМ (проверка/настройка ключей с ответами)"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №1"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №2"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №3"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №4"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №5"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №6"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №7"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №8"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №9"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №10"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №11"))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №12"))
        self.groupBox_2.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Общие настройки"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузить ключ с ответами"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сохранить данные"))
        self.label_19.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Имя файла с ключем ответа"))
        self.label_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Директория файлов для \n"
"проверки"))
        self.label_15.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вывод данных в файл типа"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", ".txt"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", ".csv"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", ".docx"))
        self.label_16.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>Директория сохранения </p><p>проверенных файлов</p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Дишифровать файлы"))
        self.label_18.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>Директория файлов с </p><p>ключем ответов</p></body></html>"))
        self.label_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ключ шифрования данных"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "Дешифровка"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_5), _translate("MainWindow", "Настройка заданий"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_4), _translate("MainWindow", "Статистика"))
        self.label_17.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-weight:600;\">ВНИМАНИЕ! ДАННАЯ ВЕРСИЯ ПРОГРАММА НАХОДИТСЯ В БЕТА ВЕРСИИ, В НЕЙ МОГУТ ПРИСУДСТВОВАТЬ</span></p><p><span style=\" font-weight:600;\">НЕ РАБОЧИЕ ФУНКЦИИ. ПОЛЬЗУЯСЬ ПРОГРАММОЙ ВЫ СОГЛАШАЕТЕСЬ С ПРАВИЛАМИ ЕЁ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЯ. </span></p><p>(c)Copyrigth by Alexandrov Andrey </p></body></html>"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @S.Nick теперь выводит вот так: `G:/PyCharm/PyCharmProject/projectSAFTD_x32/OGE/name.txt
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='G:/PyCharm/PyCharmProject/projectSAFTD_x32/OGE/name.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1251'>
b`

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: @S.Nick я добавил пример.

Comment: @S.Nick можете помочь с вопросом?

Comment: если вы предоставили воспроизводимый пример, то я посмотрю его чуть позже.

Comment: @S.Nick хорошо, пример прикреплен выше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`readline()`** — это файловый метод, который помогает прочитать одну полную строку из данного файла. 
Он имеет завершающую новую строку (“**`\n`**”) в конце возвращаемой строки. 
Вы также можете использовать параметр размера, чтобы получить определенную длину линии.

**Syntax**

```
file.readline(size)
```

где, **`size`**: (необязательно) Здесь вы можете указать число, целочисленное значение для `readline()`.
Он получит строку такого размера. 
По умолчанию значение size равно -1, поэтому возвращается вся строка.

Когда вы задаете `file.readline(1)` - что вы ожидаете получить?

Смотрите что получается если например мы имеем файл:

**1111.txt**

```
привет
hello
теперь_выводит_вот_так
а_как_вам_надо?
что_у_вас_в_текстовом_файле?
и_что_вы_хотите_там_прочитать?
7
все_работает_как_вы_написали.
9
10
11world
12ok
```

---

```
    ...

    with open(directory_file, "r", encoding='utf-8') as file:
        print(file)
        
        self.number_1_decrypto = file.readline(1)
        self.number_2_decrypto = file.readline(2)
        self.number_3_decrypto = file.readline(3)
        self.number_4_decrypto = file.readline(4)
        self.number_5_decrypto = file.readline(5)
        self.number_6_decrypto = file.readline(6)
        self.number_7_decrypto = file.readline(7)
        self.number_8_decrypto = file.readline(8)
        self.number_9_decrypto = file.readline(9)
        self.number_10_decrypto = file.readline(10)
        self.number_11_decrypto = file.readline(11)
        self.number_12_decrypto = file.readline(12)
        
        print(f'self.number_1_decrypto = {self.number_1_decrypto}')
        print(f'self.number_2_decrypto = {self.number_2_decrypto}')
        print(f'self.number_3_decrypto = {self.number_3_decrypto}')
        print(f'self.number_4_decrypto = {self.number_4_decrypto}')
        print(f'self.number_5_decrypto = {self.number_5_decrypto}')
        print(f'self.number_6_decrypto = {self.number_6_decrypto}')
        print(f'self.number_7_decrypto = {self.number_7_decrypto}')
        print(f'self.number_8_decrypto = {self.number_8_decrypto}')
        print(f'self.number_9_decrypto = {self.number_9_decrypto}')
        print(f'self.number_10_decrypto= {self.number_10_decrypto}')            
        print(f'self.number_11_decrypto= {self.number_11_decrypto}')
        print(f'self.number_12_decrypto= {self.number_12_decrypto}')
    ...
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Читаем [Python readline() Method with Examples](https://www.guru99.com/python-file-readline.html#:%7E:text=What%20is%20Python%20readline%3F,specific%20length%20of%20the%20line.)

Мне показалось что вам нужна следующая реализация, проверьте:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from crypto import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import rsa


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowTitle("Automatic OGE verification system ver.00.04.75")

        (self.key_pub, self.key_priv) = rsa.newkeys(1024)

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.information)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.app_information)

    def information(self):
        self.key_crypto = self.lineEdit_13.text()
        self.directory_file_ver = self.lineEdit_14.text()
        self.directory_save = self.lineEdit_15.text()
        self.directory_key = self.lineEdit_16.text()
        self.name_key = self.lineEdit_17.text()

        self.key_task()

    def key_task(self):
        self.number_1 = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.number_2 = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        self.number_3 = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        self.number_4 = self.lineEdit_4.text()
        self.number_5 = self.lineEdit_5.text()
        self.number_6 = self.lineEdit_6.text()
        self.number_7 = self.lineEdit_7.text()
        self.number_8 = self.lineEdit_8.text()
        self.number_9 = self.lineEdit_9.text()
        self.number_10 = self.lineEdit_10.text()
        self.number_11 = self.lineEdit_11.text()
        self.number_12 = self.lineEdit_12.text()

        self.key_task_crypto()

    def key_task_crypto(self):
        self.number_1_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_1.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_2_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_2.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_3_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_3.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_4_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_4.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_5_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_5.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_6_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_6.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_7_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_7.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_8_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_8.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_9_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_9.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_10_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_10.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_11_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_11.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_12_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_12.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)

        self.load_key_task_crypto()

    def load_key_task_crypto(self):
        k = [self.number_1_crypto, self.number_2_crypto, self.number_3_crypto, self.number_4_crypto,
             self.number_5_crypto, self.number_6_crypto, self.number_7_crypto, self.number_8_crypto,
             self.number_9_crypto, self.number_10_crypto, self.number_11_crypto, self.number_12_crypto,
             self.key_crypto]

        directory_save_key = self.directory_key + self.name_key + ".txt"

        with open(directory_save_key, "w") as f:
            f.write("\n".join(str(item) for item in k))

    def app_information(self):
        directory_file, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, ".", "*.txt")

        print(f'directory_file = {directory_file} <----')                  
        
#        x = open(directory_file, 'r')
#        print(x)
        
        with open(directory_file, "r", encoding='utf-8') as file:
            print(file)

# ----------------------------------------------> vvvvvvvvvv <--------------------- !!! 
            self.number_1_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_2_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_3_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_4_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_5_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_6_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_7_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_8_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_9_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_10_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_11_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_12_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            
            print(f'self.number_1_decrypto = {self.number_1_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_2_decrypto = {self.number_2_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_3_decrypto = {self.number_3_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_4_decrypto = {self.number_4_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_5_decrypto = {self.number_5_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_6_decrypto = {self.number_6_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_7_decrypto = {self.number_7_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_8_decrypto = {self.number_8_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_9_decrypto = {self.number_9_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_10_decrypto= {self.number_10_decrypto}')            
            print(f'self.number_11_decrypto= {self.number_11_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_12_decrypto= {self.number_12_decrypto}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Settings что не так?

Comment: сделано все верно!